# ELB OutofService if EKS worker nodes in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I create a VPC with 1 public subnets and 2 private subnets like this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html)

Then I create a new EKS cluster, select 3 subnets. For EKS workers node, I only put in 2 private subnets and this node can be register to cluster. 
So I tried to create a sample project in [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html), everything look good, pod, services, elb can be created. But ELB health check failed, it said "OutofService". In security group worknode, I allowed all traffic for ELB
[image]
I there anything I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points you can verify are whether 
* elb security group is opened up in worker instance security group
* check whether ELB subnets are the the same Availability Zone as the worker nodes

Comment: Yes, that's a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Multiple things were mentioned in this solution. Which part solved your problem?